# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError using native interface

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have this cpp file:

```cpp
//pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.cpp
#include <pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pkgnative_tries__1native_NativeSystem_println
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);
    cout << nativeString;

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
}
```

pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h:

```hpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem */

#ifndef _Included_pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
#define _Included_pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
 * Method:    println
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pkgnative_tries__1native_NativeSystem_println
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

This is the java class:

```
import java.io.File;

public class NativeSystem {
    static {
        try {
            System.load(new File(NativeSystem.class.getResource("native_files/pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.dll").toURI()).getPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static native void println(String obj);
}
```

When i call `NativeSystem.println("abc");` it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NativeSystem.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at NativeSystem.println(Native Method)
    at NativeTries.main(NativeTries.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Does anyone know why? I'm sure the dll is loaded, the `catch` block in the `static` block in `NativeSystem` doesn't execute. I've never encountered this before. How can i fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the DLL is included, but somehow the method is not found?

Comment: @ppeterka66 Thought that too, but I don't think so... The header file is generated by `javah`, so the method name must be right, and the function name in the `cpp` file has to be the same as the one in the header. Theoretically everything is fine, but the error message is still there :/

Comment: @ppeterka66 Hmmm, no, i also tried with `System.loadLibrary` (omitting the extension) but i get the same error

Comment: is the dll on your working path?

Comment: @OscarG Yes. Otherwise it would have fired something like "file not found in java.library.path". By the way, it's written in the question, the `catch` block when the application tries to load the library never gets executed, so the library gets succesfully loaded.

Comment: yes, the thing is that it all seems correct to me, so I was just thinking on the hard time I had the last time I worked with JNI like 3 months ago making my app finding the dll... if I come up with something else I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

C++ does mangle the names of functions in the DLLs, if you are on windows you can use dumpbin to see what the function name looks like in dll.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Don't have the reputation for it sadly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the line "native_files/pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.dll" is seems messy, please check it.

I have resolved the same type of issue by adding

```
System.loadLibrary("your library name");
```

To each method where they are needed
and please also verify that the path of **library** is correct.

Pls ref this for further information. [UnsatisfiedLinkError in native method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550949/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-native-method/21772018#21772018)

Thanks