# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]: 72 cannot locate '__isnanf'

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk

I'm trying to run an app using apv native library for android.

I've changed the package names in the library and compiled it using the script included in the library and also separately using `ndk-build` command in the terminal. I placed the resultant .so files in the jniLibs folder like this:-

- `jniLibs/armeabi/libapv.so`
- `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libapv.so`
- `jniLibs/x86/libapv.so`

All of this has made me successfully run the app on Nexus 4, Moto G and Xperia T but it doesn't run on other devices (Galaxy Tab 10 inch, Galaxy S3, Asus Memopad) and throws the above error.

I don't know what's amiss here. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Which version of the NDK did you use?

Comment: A possibly related problem is mentioned here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/95755/

Comment: @rmtheis I'm using the revision 10

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r - please edit the question. Run `libapv.so` through `ndk-depends` and add the output to the question. Also, there is no `jniLibs` folder. You should update the question to match your comments provided in maven's answer.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue by any chance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're using latest version of NDK (NDKr10c) right? I faced same problem with cocos2d-x & NDKr10c
-> Revert to NDKr9d -> it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

do check my answer  [UnsatisfiedLinkError in native method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550949/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-native-method/21772018#21772018)

[image]

this error is

## Thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a native for which an implementation could not be found.

u need to create

.so files for every proessor type in andorid systems

I have resolved this issue by adding

```
System.loadLibrary(".so file name");
```

To each method where they are created

LIKE THIS:

```
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> word_quiz(String qry) {
    System.loadLibrary("sqliteX");
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH+ "/sk1.db", null);
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
    try {
        mcursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            list1.add(mcursor.getString(0));
            list2.add(mcursor.getString(1));
        } while (mcursor.moveToNext());

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (MainActivity.logcat_status) {
            Log.e("Error", e + "");
        }
    }
    mcursor.close();
    mcursor = null;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> final_list = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    final_list.put("list1", list1);
    final_list.put("list2", list2);
    db.close();
    return final_list;

}
```

[reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore-snapshot/+/ics-mr1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.java)

Comment: I have, as already mentioned in the description, added the .so files for these 3 types. I've checked the log and the error is thrown when calling `System.loadLibrary()` method

Comment: the reason behind is that either ur .so is different as needed in the code or the method is not present

Comment: I already have a different .so file generated for armeabi-v7a

Comment: and yes I've tried with only armeabi and armeabi-v7a.. its still the same.. runs fine on my Nexus 4 but fails to run on Galaxy Tab 10 inch

Comment: what are the SDK version of both of them ?

Comment: minSdkVersion = 14

targetSdkVersion = 19

Android version on Nexus 4 = 4.4.4

Android version on Galaxy Tab = 4.0.4

Comment: that error is only 
Thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a native for which an implementation could not be found.

Comment: ok.. I found a certain similarity in the devices it fails to run. They are all cortex(based) processors.. Krait processors run the app fine

Comment: have You found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too . 
My app runs ok with armeabi both on phone and pad.so I add  armeabi-v7a and run both devices , it is ok . but when i delete armeabi-v7a , then run on phone and pad , the app on phone have the following exception ":UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]: 72 cannot locate '__isnanf'", but the pad does not . so , I add armeabi-v7a to project again ,the app on the phone works successfully.

Comment: I was building the .so files from the source. I vaguely remember I had to downgrade ndk version to R8b and everything went soomthly after that.