# Keep .so files from being trimmed when use Proguard in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, quickblox, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using Proguard in my android app to reduce the number of methods ([see this](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71)). For that I have coded some lines in **proguard-project.txt** file. All the jars work well after the necessary commands. But when I try to integrate Video Chat part of Quickblox, they provide us a **.so** that I would have to integrate. So I just keep it in the *libs\armeabi\libilbc-codec.so* path as guided by them. Now the project runs well when I run it without Proguard, but when I compile it with Proguard, it gives me with following error:

```
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-34829
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at com.quickblox.videochat.core.objects.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.run(AudioRecorder.java:196)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ilbc-codec: findLibrary returned null
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<init>(Codec.java:16)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:5)
11-21 18:18:19.171: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    ... 2 more
11-21 18:18:19.281: E/copybit(19825): Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
```

I am very noob to using Proguard as well as NDK, so can anyone guide me as how can I overcome this issue? I have added Native support by Right clicking on project -> Android Tool -> Add Native Support.. and selected the .so file I have been using. So can anyone suggest any solution or the lines that I would have to write to this .so file to work ?

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**: 
After following @ph0b's comment, I tried following steps:

I have removed BDK supprot from the app following [this tutorial](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.in/2011/12/removing-native-support-from-android.html) and also unzipped the apk as per his steps and I am getting my "libilbc-codec.so" library under "/lib/armeabi". But still getting the below error. So what might be wrong now ??

```
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-455
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049): Process: com.hypersquare, PID: 6049
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.hypersquare-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.hypersquare-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libilbc-codec.so"
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<init>(Codec.java:16)
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:5)
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at com.quickblox.videochat.core.objects.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.run(AudioRecorder.java:196)
11-24 12:12:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(6049):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872804/unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found) and for [resolving](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21772018/1761003)

Answer (score 2):

Proguard shouldn't remove .so files, I guess your issue comes from something else.

When you use "add native support" from eclipse, eclipse creates an empty ndk library project (a jni folder with empty sources and a sample Makefile).

So when you build your app, eclipse empties `libs/*/` folders, then build and install the newly created library here.

If you don't use the NDK yourself (not compiling any sources with it), you should remove the `jni` folder and its content from your project, and put the .so files you need to be packaged into your apk, directly inside `libs/(armeabi|x86|...)` folders (btw, it's *jniLibs* instead of *libs* when using Android Studio).

In order to check what .so files are getting packaged into your app, you can open your APK as a zip file and look under the `lib/(armeabi|x86|...)` folders.

Comment: @ph0b- Thanks a lot for the reply man, but it still doesn't work. Please check my edit in question. Am I going in right direction or not ?

Comment: yes! but that's weird it's still not working... can you check if your lib is getting installed on the device ? You can run `adb shell ls /data/app/com.hypersquare-1/lib/arm/` or use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app. Also, try uninstalling and installing your app again, just in case.

Comment: Hi ph0b, the stack of comments were increasing here so I took you in a private chat. Can you please look into my issue there. Thanks a lot for support.